# Meteor: how to get the variable content as key for Mongo query

Tags: meteor

```
var key= "features.1.attributes.2";
SurveyDefinitions.update({"_id": "5XCcprsk2wgbyvman"}, {$set: {"features.1.attributes.2" : "update-fails"}});
SurveyDefinitions.update({"_id": "5XCcprsk2wgbyvman"}, {$set: {key : "update-works"}});
```

While the first update with inline string works, the second with an identical key but stored in a variable does not work.

Instead it is written to the document as a {key:"update-works"} entry, thus key is not evaluated but taken as the name. How is it possible that Meteor evaluates the variable 'key'?

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {};
data[key]=event.target.value;
console.log(data);
var result= SurveyDefinitions.update({"_id": masterTemplate._id},  {$set:data});
```

Comment: To expand on this answer, when you include the inline 'key' attribute, javascript interprets that as a literal. In Roland's answer, he's correctly using the key's value to set the data object. An alternative (if you're using ES2015) is SurveyDefinitions.update({"_id": "5XCcprsk2wgbyvman"}, {$set: {[key] : "update-works"}}); -- Note the brackets around the key, which is a new feature called " Computed (dynamic) property names". More Info: https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#enhanced-object-literals